# unable to install package with bower

Tags: git, bower

I am trying to use a build script to build a project. The build runs successfully if ran on developers machine, on my machine or I run it manually on the teamcity agent but fails if the the build is ran through teamcity on the same agent.
This is the error that I am getting.

"git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git";, exit code of #128

I saw a solution to run the command
"git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://"

this also did not resolve the problem.

the error comes when the command "bower install" is executed. the content of bower.json are

{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.16.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "jquery-ui": "1.11.4",
    "Font-Awesome": "4.6.3"
  } 
}

The Agent is a windows server 2016 with Visual studio 2017 enterprise installed. I installed nodes v6.11.0LTS manually and bower 1.8.0 using npm installed.

BTW the error keeps coming on different packages, Its not always on the same package name.
I also tried cache clean but It did not work as well.

Comment: are you using privat bower repository? (is there a .bowerrc file in project)

Comment: Not using private repo, Also no .bowerrc file present.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio/msbuild was using different version of node and eventually npm, bower and git although the latest version were already installed on the Agent but were not being used by msbuild.
had to go in to the webexternal folder of visual studio and update node and then bower.
search for git in visual studio folder mine was at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd" had to update git from visual studio.

So although both git and node latest version were installed and were in the path, ms build used the version which were available in visual studio. updated git from visual studio and updated node.js by going into the web external folder of visual studio openign and cmd and ran command to update node. once node was updated I installed bower. Then msbuild started using the latest versions and I did not face the problem again.
BTW I restarted the Agent after the installation as well, dont know if that helped as well.